# Does QNativeGesture works on Linux / Windows, given that the hardware supports it?

Tags: linux, qt, qt5

I want to add swipe gestures in my application based on Qt5. The application is intended to run primarily on Linux (laptop). I was just not able to write code because I couldn't understand how to use the class (no example code was available).

The touchpad driver supports swipe gestures (libinput). Also, synaptics (on my system at least) support multi-finger touch.

Can someone please guide me about how to use the API, and provide with some example code?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean `QNativeGestureEvent`? You probably shouldn't mess with `QNativeGestureEvent` and use the higher-level framework: see [Gestures in Widgets and Graphics View](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/gestures-overview.html). The `QNativeGestureEvent` used to be only available on OS X; it's not really an API that's meant for wide consumption.

Alas, the `QNativeGestureEvent`s are delivered to the widgets themselves. You would react to them by reimplementing `QObject::event` and acting on the event:

```
class MyWidget : public QWidget {
  typedef base_type = QWidget;
  ...
  bool QWidget::event(QEvent * ev) override {
    if (ev->type() == QEvent::NativeGesture) {
      auto g = static_Cast<QNativeGestureEvent*>(ev);
      ...
      return true; // if event was recognized and processed
    }
    return base_type::event(ev);
  }
};
```

But don't do that.